# Local by Flywheel - Trying to import an existing site and database for offline development. Getting error: "Error establishing a database connection"

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress

I'm taking over an existing site to make updates for a client. The original developers dumped the files on the hosting provider, imported the database, and left. They never set up the site so it's not live and I don't have access to the site's WP admin panel. Therefore, using plugins is not an option.

I want to work on the site offline so I can replace the files when I am finished making changes. I exported all files and subfolders under public_html via FTP, then I checked wp-config.php to see what database was being used and exported that database via phpMyAdmin.

I placed the exported .sql file along with the site files downloaded via FTP and created a .zip archive.

[image: Files to be imported to Local by Flywheel]

I then open Local by Flywheel and drag the .zip file into the program so it can be imported.

The first problem that arises is I notice that flywheel disregards the existing wp-config.php file and creates its own.

[image: Overridden server information]

Navigating to the development site it asks me to complete the setup process for a new site which is not correct. It should be using the existing database.

When I open Sequel Pro, there are two databases, the first one is "local" which was created by Flywheel, then there's the actual database that I want to use.

[image: The two databases]

I then navigate to the site's files and update wp-config.php to use the server that I want it to use.

[image: The updated wp-config.php file.]

When I go back to Flywheel I can see that it's now referencing the original database.

[image: Flywheel noticing the changes]

When I go to the development site I am now met with an error message saying  "Error establishing a database connection"

[image: The site error]

I then view the mysql logs and see this message:

```
2019-09-11T11:56:28.787881Z 30 [Note] Access denied for user 'yornbfmy_rpg'@'localhost' (using password: YES)
```

The user and password are the exact same ones on the wp-config.php file from the server. Like I said, I didn't create this site. The original developers put all the files in there and called it a day. Did they give me the wrong credentials? I'm very confused, and WordPress isn't my strongest skill. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would check if the user `yornbfmy_rpg` exists in mysql database and if it has the corrects rights.

Comment: So I did two things before the site started working. The first thing I did was create a user yornbfmy_rpg using Sequel Pro. When I added the user the site stopped giving me the database error but would redirect to the live site for some reason. I checked my local database and replaced the home and siteurl rows in the options table. It was still redirecting so I opened a new browser and suddenly it started working. I suppose it was something funky in my cache. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Just install the fresh Wordpress using flywheel.
After that copy your wp-content folder in newly installed wordpress.
Means just overwrite the or first delete the wp-content and then paste your backup wp-content in it.
After that open your phpmyadmin using flywheel i thought that its named with adminer, click on that and it will open the phpmyadmin for you in browser.
After that delete select all tables and delete it.
For safer side try to import database using wp-cli if you have not enough import memory size.
On phpmyadmin click on import and select your backup db file and click on Go button.
If you have successfully import the db, now its time to change and replace the old links with your local links.
for this i have used this utility.
https://github.com/interconnectit/Search-Replace-DB

Let me know if this above approach is helpful for you to setup the local environment.